# Android Multiple Implementations of one element of the same Layout

Tags: android

[image]

As showed in the picture above. Android Studio shows that I have two elements with the same +id in the same layout. But that is not true.
I would like to know why this happen.

Thanks

Comment: Probably it's a bug on Android Studio, you can show us your `activity_checknumber.xml` and we'll see if there is something wrong. You also can try with menu `File -> Invalidate cache / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart`, sometimes Android Studio has the symbols wrong.

Comment: Perhaps there are two versions of your `activity_checknumber.xml` - for example for different screen dimensions. Go to both declarations and check if the files are the same.

Comment: @Victoria thanks for the answer, but there are no two versions.
In that case you would see something like this:
**activity_checknumber.xml (layout)
  activity_checknumber.xml (layout-large)**

Comment: @Arturo your answer solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help, remember marking the answer as solved :)

Comment: @Arturo can you post it as an answer and then I click it as solved.

Comment: Doesn't matter, mark your answer as solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arturo your answer solved the problem.

> File -> Invalidate Cache/ Restart...-> Invalidate and Restart.

Thanks a lot.