# Android Studio- Multiple Implementations issue at android:id

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am beginner of Android studio. I got issue in layout at **android:id** with multiple implementation. I searched but it's showing links with- [Include same layout multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195454/include-same-layout-multiple-times)- and [Can I use the same id in different layout-Android Multiple Implementations of one element of the same Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333624/can-i-use-the-same-id-in-different-layout-in-android) etc.,...

I tried to search on web too but I didn't find related information .The problem is in a layout I have used. The Button id is `android:id="@+id/button_actionpage"` and also I have used the Button id below in *DatePicker* Button with `android:layout_below="@+id/button_actionpage"`. So I got a issue in *Activity.java* with an error                                                                              `"java.lang.NullPointerException" due multiple implementation android:id in layout`

I can't get a solution about **android:id** with multiple implementation in layout.

**Here is my screen shot**

[image]

**Here is my layout code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_store"
        android:text="Store information"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Information"
        android:id="@+id/button_show"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date:"
        android:id="@+id/date_reg"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ActionPage"
        android:id="@+id/button_actionpage"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_actionpage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat:**

> 07-30 15:58:14.041 29642-29642/com.raj.androidapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.raj.androidapplication, PID: 29642
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.raj.androidapplication/com.raj.androidapplication.LoginPrefActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error
>   inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2335)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
>                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25:
>   Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:397)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1513)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.raj.androidapplication.LoginPrefActivity.onCreate(LoginPrefActivity.java:13)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697) 
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:383)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1513) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.raj.androidapplication.LoginPrefActivity.onCreate(LoginPrefActivity.java:13) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697) 
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of
>   null array
>                                                                                       at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:226)
>                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getTextArray(Resources.java:518)
>                                                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getTextArray(TypedArray.java:771)
>                                                                                       at android.preference.ListPreference.(ListPreference.java:51)
>                                                                                       at android.preference.ListPreference.(ListPreference.java:65)
>                                                                                       at android.preference.ListPreference.(ListPreference.java:69)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:383) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1513) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.raj.androidapplication.LoginPrefActivity.onCreate(LoginPrefActivity.java:13) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)

Comment: what is error line no and what is written there ?

Comment: Is this is the layout you referenced in the activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: In the code snippet above You are closing the Button tag twice.
Remove the closing tag after "android:layout_marginTop="116dp"/>"  in the button with id "button_actionpage" and try again.

Comment: i think problem with not this layout, reason behind this **problem is may b you have used same id name in some other layout too** and thats why it's getting conflict at the time of finding your element **try by changing your id name..**

Comment: @UttamPanchasara there is no id common in any other layout..

Comment: @Prasad Yes I referred it

Comment: @Amylinn Read the question properly..

Comment: hmm have you clear your project ?? if not then try by clearing your project and then rebuild

Comment: @UttamPanchasara Yes i have cleared my project.

Comment: showing two id coz... one is your actual id of Button and second which is you used to set layout_below in DatePicker. you only have to select Button ID

Comment: @uttam panchasara I selected Button id but the problem is not performing action while clicking on Button in emulator.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this ? Were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

As per [Android Multiple Implementations of one element of the same Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32249823/android-multiple-implementations-of-one-element-of-the-same-layout)

> File -> Invalidate Cache/ Restart...-> Invalidate and Restart.

should solve the problem